# PHP/Mysql Connection Time

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a script which attempts to stop long running queries on a MySQL server. The logic - when the server starts to slow down for whatever reason, it accumulates a rush of queries as each user refreshes his page, each connection hanging in a queue, not being stopped by PHP's time limit, and preventing new connections. In addition, a mistaken query might use a lot of resources.

I have encountered a strange situation recently with this system. We have two cron scripts running constantly. Normally, their connections don't have a time more than 1 in "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST". For some reason, the other day, these connections were increased in time 50+ seconds, but they did not have a query attached to them. I was not able to see this live, but it was recorded in the log clearly enough to be traced back to these processes.

My question is why would these connections suddenly increase in their duration? Especially, why, given that they did not have a query, but were in sleep mode. (As proof, my logs showed Time=78,State='',Info=0 - not sure why 0). In PHP, I am using PDO with the standard options, except a ATTR_TIMEOUT of 30 for CLI scripts. Also, there was reported a slowness on the site at the time of these problem connections.

Comment: I have a similar problem where every 49th request has a slight connection delay . Did you make any progress?

Comment: I'm not sure how your problem relates to this one, but no. I just removed the error from my logs as I didn't think it was serious.